# Conjugate rotation transformation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, projective-geometry

I am trying to apply a certain rotation to an image, but it doesn't work as expected. The rotation I have is:

```
[0.109285   0.527975    0.000000    
-0.527975   0.109285    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    1.000000]
```

Which should be a rotation of ~78 degrees around the camera center (or the Z axis if you prefer).
To build a homography, as there is no translation component, I use the formula: `K * R * K^-1` (infinite homography).

The code I use to transform the image (320x240) is:

```
cv::warpPerspective(image1, image2, K * R * K.inv(), image1.size());
```

where K is:

```
[276.666667 0.000000    160.000000  
0.000000    276.666667  120.000000  
0.000000    0.000000    1.000000]
```

The resulting matrix from `K * R * K.inv()` is:

```
[0.109285   0.527975    79.157461   
-0.527975   0.109285    191.361865  
0.000000    0.000000    1.000000]
```

The result should just be a rotation of the image, but the image gets "zoomed out" like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't you get the transformation matrix using `getRotationMatrix2D`?

Comment: @Miki I will try that, but I would also like to understand why it doesn't work, because I will have to apply rotation on other axis later on.

Comment: Ok, it was just to rule out obvious solutions :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my rotation matrix was wrong.